# Git fetch timeout with Jenkins 2.333

Tags: git, jenkins

I installed a new Jenkins 2.333.

```
Running a normal free style projects works as expected.

Whenever I run a pipeline with git, it keeps running forever without ending.
```

and some part of the console output log is:

Checking out Revision a5a4369cfb0491a55028a5d0cc50394e52c2dad4 (refs/remotes/origin/main)

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f a5a4369cfb0491a55028a5d0cc50394e52c2dad4 # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -b main a5a4369cfb0491a55028a5d0cc50394e52c2dad4 # timeout=10

Please see attached image for complete console output log and assist me with a suggestion on how to resolve this.

Thank you in advance.

```
Can some please help me out on how to resolve this.

Thank you in advance.
[screenshot showing the error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgd9h.png
```

The code is a sample console output log that I see each time this happens.

[image: Click here to view Image]

Comment: Nothwistanding @jessehouwing's efforts, consider [reformatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note that `# timeout=10` is not part of the `git fetch` command. It's jenkins' way of saying "I, jenkins, will only wait ten seconds for this to finish, then I give up." It did not actually give up so it looks like the fetch completed.

Comment: Thank you @torek. 
But I waited for hours, yet it did not complete. It keeps rolling and rolling.

Please any other suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the *Git operation* completed, and *then* something (else) went wrong. What, why, etc., is going to be a Jenkins issue rather than a Git one. I can't prove that from your output though. Ian W's request to reformat and otherwise improve your question still stands too though. See the [ask] link.